# Serre FAC book by McLennan

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, coherent-sheaves

I am planning to read Serre's FAC paper. I came to know that there is a book/notes by Andy McLennan, containing the commutative algebra background as well as an english translation of the FAC (Ravi Vakil's blog mentions it: https://math216.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/2014-version/)

But the link to the book seems to be broken. I could not find it elsewhere. Does someone know of a working link?

Comment: [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english) does not have a working link to McLennan, but it might help you (or anyone else who comes across this question).

Comment: I've heard that French math isn't too bad. But you are in luck: https://web.archive.org/web/20180322174308/http://cupid.economics.uq.edu.au/mclennan/Algebra/fac_trans.pdf. Presumably you could email him as well.

Comment: @TokenToucan thanks so much!

Answer (score 8):

*The Algebra of Coherent Algebraic Sheaves with an Explicated Translation of Serre's "Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents"*  is now available at my personal website

https://andymclennan.droppages.com/Books/

or more directly from

https://andymclennan.droppages.com/fac_trans.pdf  (thanks to Martin for pointing this out)

Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Although the link https://andymclennan.droppages.com/fac_trans.pdf (after omitting `/Books` from the URL) works at the moment. The same link is given also in this answer on MO: [Serre's FAC in English](https://mathoverflow.net/q/14404#248951).

Comment: It's intriguing to see the author of the book respond; but we still ask that you explicitly mention your affiliation with the site you link to, as per our [promotion policy.](/help/promotion)

Comment: In continuation to @tripleee, and the moderator that declined my flag on this post. Not disclosing ones affiliation with a linked resource is condired SPAM according to the policy tripleee linked.

Comment: I have edited my answer to describe the resource as my personal website.  If this is not adequate, please let me know.